# selected item won't display

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

All I want to do is show the selected item below the master list o' items. I've done this before, but for some reason it's just not behaving and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

the html (trimmed down to just the relevant part):

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="$parent.selectUser($index)" ng-model="$index">
        {{user.userName}}
    </li>
</ul>

<p>Selected: {{selected.userName}}, #<b>{{$index}}</b></p>
```

the js:

```
(function (app) {
    app.controller('UsersController', [ '$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.selectUser = function ($index) {
            $scope.selected = $index;
            console.info('selected1=' + $index);
        };
        $scope.selected = null;
    }]);
});
```

The console log shows up with the index of the selection, but nothing happens in the last line of the html -- no selected.userName, no $index. I've tried all kinds of variations and nothing happens. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

(note: I'm not sure I'm using ng-model there correctly, either, but that seems to be incidental to whether or not I can get the selected $index to show up.)

Comment: Why are you using `$parent` selectUser. You don't require it, if the method is on parent scope it would be available on child scope.

Comment: I thought ng-repeat creates isolated/child scope, and I wanted to keep any edits of the selection as part of the parent scope so those would then be available elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `$index` outside the `ng-repeat` which would not work, as `$index` is only available inside the `ng-repeat` context.

Since you are setting

$scope.selected = $index;

you need to use `selected` variable

I think what you want is to select  user on clicking. This should be done like this.

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="selectUser(user,$index)" ng-model="$index">
        {{user.userName}}
    </li>
</ul>

<p>Selected: {{selected.userName}}, #<b>{{index}}</b></p>
```

Your controller would have

```
$scope.selectUser = function (user,index) {
            $scope.selected = user;
            $scope.index=index;
        };
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! One note: the controller's last line should be $scope.index = $index -- when I did it without the $, I got an 'undefined' msg. Adding that $ made it work exactly like I needed. Yay!

Comment: Depends upon the function parameter, my fn parameter uses `index`.